# how to make smart contract erc1155 receiver?

Tags: solidity, openzeppelin, erc-1155

i have a smart contract that receives ERC1155 tokens but it needs to be ERC1155 Receiver, how to properly implement the ERC1155TokenReceiver interface?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

openzeppelin has already implemented it in the following library,
import this from openzepplin:

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC1155/utils/ERC1155Holder.sol";

contract myContract is ERC1155Holder{}
```

Comment: What happens if we don't use the "is ERC1155Holder" keyword after the contract's name?

Comment: @SinaRahimi it means the myContrac wont inherit ERCHolder, it wont have its methods available